# Recursive rename using 'rename'

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I'm trying to rename some files in a WordPress installation.
After backing up and restoring some names have '#U00f8' instead of 'ø' which makes the images not work on the site.

So I need to rename all images with that string in it to the proper letter.

I have worked my way to this:

```
rename -n 's/\#U00f8/ø/i' *
```

..which should work, but it doesn't?

I have also found out there are several versions of the rename utility. Mine is this:

> rename from util-linux 2.32.1

Can anyone help figure this out?

Comment: Can you install another version of `rename`? On older versions of Ubuntu, I think the canonical name was `prename`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As `man rename` tells you, your version of `rename` doesn't use regular expressions. Fortunately, you can still use it for your use case:

```
rename '#U00f8' ø *
```

It only replaces the first occurrence, so you might need to run it `while ls *\#U00f8*`.